# ¿Como soluciono este error al ejecutar mi primera app en iPhone?

Tags: swift, xcode

Me sale este error al querer simular mi programa en mi iPhone 6s.

error: Task failed with exit 1 signal 0

Pero por el contrario al usar un simulador no me da ningún error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema podría ser por varias razones. Puedes intentar lo siguiente:

1. Certificado caducado. Actualiza tu certificado y el perfil de aprovisionamiento.
2. Mover el  certificado de desarrollador de iOS de local a sistema usando Key Chain. Cerrar Xcode > Abrir llavero > Encuentra el certificado de desarrollador de iOS en Local > Arrastre y suelte el certificado de Local a la pestaña Sistema > Ingrese la contraseña de administrador cuando se le solicite > Inicie Xcode y cree un proyecto para su dispositivo.
3. Otra forma: Cerrar Xcode > Limpiar datos derivados > Abre Xcode > Limpia el Producto > Ejecuta tu aplicación.
4. Reinicia tu computador

Comment: He realizado lo que mencionas pero ahora me sale esto : https://ibb.co/bNnpLx